# notepad++ find and replace 0 line fix

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

Okay, so Im trying to replace a line like this

> 00010 (0x000A)

with something like:

> 0010 (0x000A)

Basically just removing the first `0` from a string of 5 numbers. The file is about 134k lines. So I just want to remove the first `0` from a line of 5 numbers in length, to make the final string 4 numbers.

I've been reading on the find function in Notepad++ using regular expressions, but for the life of me, I really cannot wrap my head around how it functions. Very confusing stuff.

So an answer would be great—an answer with some explanation would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have Notepad++ on this machine so can't test right now, but this regex *should* work.

Find: `^[0-9]([0-9]{4})$`

Replace: `\1`

Breaking that down, it matches the start of the string, followed by a character in the range 0-9, followed by four more of those characters, capturing them, then the end of the string, and replaces it with the first capture group.

Comment: Says it cant find the text when I put that in.  However, I just did [0-9]([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]) with a replace of /1 and it seemed to fix it!

Comment: That's fair enough, I couldn't remember the exact syntax of Notepad++ regex. Glad you fixed it!

Comment: Oh man, this is crazy. Thanks a lot man, seems to have done exactly what I need it to do.  Love the explanation too, as it kinda helps me get ahold of the syntax.  Ill checkmark it the second I can!

Comment: I think you need to wait a few minutes, wait another 10 mins or so and try again.

Comment: The above regex won;t work for Notepad++. Notepad++ supports a subset of the posix regex. For example it does not support the repetition

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if it supported that or not. The OP managed to find a solution based on this one though.